# How to disable JFrame as long as another JFrame is opened (without JDialog?)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Cheers, lads.

I am currently standing in front of a minor problem, but it really drives me insane, that I'm not able to fix it.

My very first mistake was to use my main-JFrame as main-class, as well.
You will see why this is (as far as I am able to judge) a problem later...

Now I am opening a new JFrame from my main-class-main-JFrame and I want to disable it as long as the new JFrame is opened.

I've already read much about using JDialog to do this, but I did not yet managed to find a solution without having to redesign my whole sub-JFrame.

Is there an easy way to just disable the mainJFrame as long as the subJFrame is opened?
Something like:

```
JFrame subframe = new GUI_subJFrame(<params>);
this.disable();
subframe.onClose(this.enable());
```

I know this is awful and not existent source code, but I wanted to make my thought clear, accurately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has rejected the obvious, and easiest, solution.

Comment: *"I've already read much about using `JDialog` to do this, but I did not yet managed to find a solution without having to redesign my whole sub-`JFrame`."* OK, get started. The problem is not going to fix itself, and getting that functionality in a `JFrame` is harder than porting the code over from a frame to a dialog. Have you made the mistake of using the IDE's inbuilt GUI editor (without 1st understanding how to use layouts, components & models)?

Comment: (1-) `but I did not yet managed to find a solution without having to redesign my whole sub-JFrame.` - there is no reason to redesign your sub JFrame. All you do is use a JDialog instead of a JFrame. All the other methods are the same. Each component has a content pane and you add components to the content pane.

Comment: I must say I found the first "answer" really offensive, but it looks like I just did not manage to describe my situation accurately. I just wanted to say that I did not manage to really understand the JDialog-bit and it looked somehow complicated to me. Now I must say, that it just wasn't. My bordered point of view was just crappy, so to say. I now changed the JFrame to JDialog and added the line `this.setModalityType(DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE);` and it simply works.

Comment: *"I must say I found the first "answer" really offensive,"* It was a comment, (based on a close vote) not an answer. Glad you got the problem sorted.

Answer (score 3):

I just changed the "subJFrame" from `JFrame` to `JDialog` and added the following line to the constructor:

```
this.setModalityType(DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE);
```

It works fine and is not as complicated as it seemed at first glance.

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score -1):

Use `frame.dispose();` to close the frame

Comment: *"to close the frame"* Which frame? Never mind. Disposing either of them may be an answer to a question, just not this one - in which a **modal** window or dialog is required.